# Codeigniter validate form is not working

Tags: forms, codeigniter, validation

I have the same implementation for my login for and is working, but on my contact form it is not, and I have no error message just re routed to the home page.
the weird thing is if in my controller i implement the index function like this:

```
public function index() {      
   $this->myprocess();      
}
```

and my view using

```
<?php 
   $attributes = array('class' => 'form-contact', 'id' => 'myform2');
   echo form_open('contact',$attributes);
?>
```

instead of calling my function myprocess all the validations work but no use for a form with out my header footers etc.

bellow that is how i want my code to work i hope yall can help me.

my controller:

```
    <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class contact extends CI_Controller {

   function __construct()
   {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('contact_m');
    }

    public function index() 
   {      
        $data = array('title' => 'Contact', 'main_content' => 'contact_v');
        $this->load->view('template', $data);

    }

    public function myprocess(){      


        $this->form_validation->set_rules('dfname', 'Name', 'required|trim|xss_clean|max_length[40]');          
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('dfemail', 'Email', 'required|trim|xss_clean|valid_email|max_length[50]|callback__verifyemail');          
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('dfmsg', 'dfmsg', 'trim|xss_clean');

        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<br /><span class="error">', '</span>');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) // validation hasn't been passed
        {
            $this->load->view('contact_v');
        }
        else 
        {
          $form_data = array(
                            'dfname' => set_value('dfname'),
                            'dfemail' => set_value('dfemail'),
                            'dfmsg' => set_value('dfmsg')
                            );

          if ($this->contact_m->SaveForm($form_data) == TRUE) 
          {
            redirect('contact/success');  
          }
          else
          {
            echo 'An error occurred saving your information. Please try again later';
          }
        }
  }

    function success()
    {
            echo 'this form has been successfully submitted with all validation being passed. All messages or logic here. Please note
            sessions have not been used and would need to be added in to suit your app';
    }

    public function verifyemail(){
        $name = $this->input->post('dfName');
        $pass = $this->input->post('dfemail');

        if($this->contact_m->email_exist($name,$pass)){ 
            if ($this->session->userdata('site_lang') == 'portuguese')
            {
                $this->form_validation->set_message('_verifyuser','Usuario Inexistente!');
            }else{
                $this->form_validation->set_message('_verifyuser','User Not Found!');
            }
            $this->index();
            return false;  

        }else{                           
            return true;            
        }
    }
}    

?>
```

my view:

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class=" col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
            <?php echo br(2)?>
            <div class="account-wall drop-shadow">

            <?php 
                $title = $this->my_library->my_title($this->session->userdata('site_lang'),FORM_CONTACT);
                echo '<h1 class="text-center login-title">'.  $title. '</h1>';
                echo br(1)
            ?>

                <?php 
                    $attributes = array('class' => 'form-contact', 'id' => 'myform2');
                    echo form_open('contact/myprocess',$attributes);
                ?>

                <p>
                    <label for="dfname">Name</span></label>
                    <?php echo form_error('dfname'); ?>
                    <input id="dfname" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" name="dfname" maxlength="40" value="<?php echo set_value('dfname'); ?>" autofocus />
                    <?php echo br(1)?>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="dfemail">Email</span></label>
                    <?php echo form_error('dfemail'); ?>
                    <input id="dfemail" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="dfemail" maxlength="50" value="<?php echo set_value('dfemail'); ?>"  />
                    <?php echo br(1)?>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="dfmsg">Message</label>
                    <?php echo form_error('dfmsg'); ?>
                    <?php echo form_textarea( array( 'name' => 'dfmsg', 'rows' => '4', 'cols' => '43', 'value' => set_value('dfmsg') ) )?>
                    <?php echo br(1)?>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <?php echo form_submit( 'submit', 'Submit'); ?>
               </p>
                 <?php form_close();?>
            </div>  
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
<?php echo br(5)?>
```

Comment: i can't find $this->load->library('form_validation'); in your code

Comment: I Loaded on my autoloader.php, like i said it is working for my login form but not for this one. even if i add this to my controller:  function __construct()
   {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
  $this->load->database();
  $this->load->helper('form');
  $this->load->helper('url');
  $this->load->model('contact_m');
    } wont work only works if i take out my

Comment: I don't see anything in your code that should be redirecting you to the home page. Is your application/config/routes.php set up correctly?

Comment: i have it like this set to home                                      $route['default_controller'] = "home";
$route['404_override'] = '';

Comment: basically only one form work right now my login form does all correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after all this days and examining all my code and re-writing all of it i found the problem.
 for some reason this line wasnt working : echo form_close(); so my first form was aways open messing up asll my validation after writing  on all of then it starting working.

Answer (score 0):

your callback function for validation need an underscore for prefix name :

```
public function _verifyemail()
```

and you need to call the process function :

```
public function index() 
   {      
        $data = array('title' => 'Contact', 'main_content' => 'contact_v');
        if($this->input->post())
           $this->myprocess();
        $this->load->view('template', $data);

    }
```

Comment: I make those changes but didnt work i press submit and no validation no error msg nothing.

Comment: In your view file you need to print errors using validation_errors function, <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>